# Computing the pole mass from a given $\overline{MS}$ mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization

Given a Yukawa coupling as a function of scale $\mu$ and a vev, therefore $m_R(μ)=Y(μ)⟨ϕ⟩$, how can I compute the corresponding pole mass $m_p$? Relations I was able to find are ([page 39](http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=3163763&fileOId=3163764)) 
$$m_p=m_R−Σ(m_P)$$

or specifically for the electron ([page 17](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic473482.files/18-renormalization.pdf))

$$ m_P =m_R - \frac{e_R^2 }{16 \pi^2}\left[ 2 (m_P-m_R) + \int dx (4m_R-2m_Px)\log( \frac{\mu^2 }{(1-x)(m_R^2-xm_P^2)}) \right] .$$

Now, what I don't understand is how these equations can be used, in practice, to compute $m_P$, if $m_R(\mu)$ is given. Any tip or reference to an example computations would be much appreciated! As the pole mass should be indendent of $\mu$, I'm confused which $\mu$ I should use in the formulas above in order to compute $m_P$.

Comment: Do you mean, is there a closed form solution?

Comment: Also,  for clarityI think $m_R(0)$ should be just $m_R$ (the argument is momentum slash $k=0$ not renormalization scale $\mu=0$)

Comment: @innisfree My problem is that I do not  understand how these formulas can be used to compute $m_P$, if $m_R(\mu)$ is known. In other words  what $\mu$ do I use to calculate $m_P$? (Some value must be used, because I have only 1 equation for two unknown quantities $m_P$ and $\mu$... ?!

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/setting-of-renormalization-scale-in-field-theory-calculations

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80972/if-renormalization-scale-is-arbitrary-why-do-we-care-about-running-couplings

Comment: The above may help. In any case, you should make it clear that your q is about picking a renormalization scale $\mu$

Comment: @innisfree thanks for the links! I always thougt that the pole mass should be independent of $\mu$?! The PDG lists pole masses without any reference to some scale, see for example page 5 here http://physik.uni-graz.at/itp/iutp/iutp_10/talks/zhou.pdf, at least for the leptons and the top. My problem is that, understandably, most papers are concerned with how one gets from the measured pole masses, the running mass at some scale, see e.g.Eq. 19 in http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1419. However I want to understand how one gets the pole mass from the running mass...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve exactly, but you can solve order by order in perturbation theory. I'm essentially following chapter 27 of Srednicki. The relation $m_P = m_R - \Sigma(m_P)$ is the one you want, but $m_P$ can only be determined implicitly. Since $\Sigma$ begins at order $\alpha$, the difference between $m_R$ and $m_P$ is $\mathcal{O}(\alpha)$, so up to $\mathcal{O}(\alpha^2)$ you can replace $m_R$ by $m_P$ inside it. So we get:

$$m_P = m_R - \Sigma(m_R) + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^2)$$

If you want to go to a higher order, suppose you compute two-loop corrections to $\Sigma$ and get $\Sigma = \alpha \Sigma_1 + \alpha^2 \Sigma_2 + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^3)$. We have the relation

$$m_P = m_R - \alpha \Sigma_1(m_P) - \alpha^2 \Sigma_2(m_P) + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^3)$$

Now inside $\Sigma_1$ we can replace $m_P$ by its $\mathcal{O}(\alpha)$ expression in terms of $m_R$, while inside $\Sigma_2$ we just set $m_P = m_R$ like we did earlier, since it's already multiplied by $\alpha^2$:

$$\begin{align}
m_P &= m_R - \alpha \Sigma_1(m_R - \alpha \Sigma_1(m_R)) - \alpha^2 \Sigma_2(m_R) + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^3) \\
&= m_R - \alpha  [\Sigma_1(m_R) - \Sigma_1'(m_R)\alpha\Sigma_1(m_R)] - \alpha^2 \Sigma_2(m_R) + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^3)\\
&= m_R - \alpha \Sigma_1(m_R) + \alpha^2 [\Sigma_1(m_R)\Sigma_1'(m_R) - \Sigma_2(m_R)] + \mathcal{O}(\alpha^3)
\end{align}$$

And so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think my problem then is: What is $m_R$ here? If it is the running mass, i.e. $m_R=m_R(\mu)$ at what energy scale $\mu$ do we evaluate it?

Comment: @JakobH: You can use whatever $\mu$ you want, because the pole mass must be independent of it. $m_R$ depends on $\mu$ in just the right way so that at each order in $\alpha$, $m_P$ is independent of $\mu$.